# how to debug a java abstractProcess using vscode

Tags: java, annotation-processing, generated, java-annotations

I created an abstractProcess to generate a code when a Pojoproperty is annotated with my custom annotation and I save it.

I have two projects:

- a project called MyAbstractProcessProject that has an annotation and my abstractProcess to process this annotation.
- a project called UseMyAbstractProcessProject, which uses the MyAbstractProcessProject dependency. and when I annotate a Pojo property and SAVE it, my MyAbstractProcessProject generates my code.

It's working, but I need to debug my MyAbstractProcessProject.

How can I trigger debug on MyAbstractProcessProject when save UseMyAbstractProcessProject
??

advanced tnx.